# Stream and the distinct operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
class C
{
    String n;

    C(String n)
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public String getN() { return n; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return this.getN().equals(((C)obj).getN());
    }
 }

List<C> cc = Arrays.asList(new C("ONE"), new C("TWO"), new C("ONE"));

System.out.println(cc.parallelStream().distinct().count());
```

but I don't understand why `distinct` returns 3 and not 2.

Comment: Aha, you're experimenting with Java 8. Try also overriding `hashCode()` in class `C`. If two `C` objects are equal, then their hash codes must be the same.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside overrided `equals` and see if `distinct` regards it.

Comment: @Jesper, I did not see any worry about `hashcode` in documents at http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--

Comment: But it seems to operate initially on `hashcode`, since that most often is more efficient than the `equals` checks. And since it is a general contract, that two equal objects _must_ have the same hash. Therefore it is a valid solution to only perform the `equals` check when the `hashcode`s are the same. And I believe that's exactly what `distinct` does

Comment: *but I don't understand why `distinct` returns 3 and not 2.*, `distinct` should be `count`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to also override the `hashCode` method in class `C`. For example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return n.hashCode();
}
```

When two `C` objects are equal, their `hashCode` methods must return the same value.

The API documentation for interface `Stream` does not mention this, but it's well-known that if you override `equals`, you should also override `hashCode`. The API documentation for `Object.equals()` mentions this:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the `hashCode` method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Apparently, `Stream.distinct()` indeed uses the hash code of the objects, because when you implement it like I showed above, you get the expected result: 2.

Comment: Likely internally the stream implementation is using HashSet which makes use of the `hashCode` method.

Comment: +1 the rule you mention is very important, don't override equals or hashcode unless you override both.  This should probably cause a compile-time error.