# Java remove entries from list where certain attributes are duplicated

Tags: java, duplicates, java-stream, collectors, streams-api

I'm new into programming and now facing a tricky problem:
I got an Object which contains a list, so the Object looks like the following:

```
public class SampleClass {
    private UUID id;
    private List<ValueObject> values;
    
    // getters, constructor, etc
}
```

The `ValueObject` contains some Strings like:

```
public class ValueObject {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    // getters, constructor, etc
}
```

I have a `SampleClass` intance which contains a list of multiple `ValueObject`s. Some of the `ValueObject`s have the same `firstName` and `lastName`.

What I want to archive is that I want to **filter out** all `ValueObject` within a `SampleClass` object having **the same** `firstName` and `lastName`. And I want to keep the **last** (according to the encounter order) `ValueObject` out of each group duplicates in the list.

I've tried the following:

```
SampleClass listWithDuplicates = // intializing SampleClass instance

listWithDuplicates.getValues().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        ValueObject::getLastname,
        Collectors.toList()
    ));
```

To group it by lastname but how do I find then the matching firstNames, because lastname can be equal but firstname can be different so I want to still keep it in my Object as it not equal. And then how to remove the duplicates?
Thank you for your help

**Update**:
The order of the list should not get affected by removing the duplicates. And the

> listWithDuplicates

holds a SampleClass Object.

Comment: you could overide equals and hashcode to check for the firstname and lastname then just compare both objects or use a set to remove de duplicates

Comment: listWithDuplicates, is this a list with sample classes or a list of valueobjects?

Comment: good question! its a list with sampleClasses.

Comment: @noob123 *"good question! its a list with sampleClasses"* - Then, please, reflect it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using *four-args version* of the Collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)), which expects the following arguments:

- *keyMapper* - a function which generates a Key out of a stream element;
- *valueMapper - a function producing Value from a stream element;
- *mergeFunctino* - a function responsible for resolving Values mapped to the same Key;
- *mapFunctory* - allows to specify the required type of Map.

In case if you can't change the implementation of the `equals/hashCode` in the `ValueObject` you can introduce an auxiliary type that would serve as a Key.

```
public record FirstNameLastName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    public FirstNameLastName(ValueObject value) {
        this(value.getFirstName(), value.getLastName);
    }
}
```

***Note:** if you're OK with overriding the `equals/hashCode` contract of the `ValueObject` on it's `firstName` and `lastName` then you don't the auxiliary type shown above. In the code below you can use `Function.identity()` as both keyMapper and valueMapper of `toMap()`.*

And the stream can be implemented like this:

```
SampleClass listWithDuplicates = // initializing your domain object
    
List<ValueObject> uniqueValues = listWithDuplicates.getValues().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        FirstNameLastName::new, // keyMapper - creating Keys
        Function.identity(),    // valueMapper - generating Values
        (left, right) -> right  // mergeFunction - resolving duplicates
        LinkedHashMap::new      // mapFuctory - LinkedHashMap is needed to preserve the encounter order of the elements
    ))
    .values().stream()
    .toList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this approach keep the order and take the latest?

Comment: @noob123 Yes it does, this requirement is reflected in the implementation of the *merge function* `(left, right) -> right`. While resolving duplicates, the latest value would be preserved.

Comment: @noob123 From your question it's not very clear what should be the resulting type - a `List`, a `Map`?

Comment: Thank you! i tried it out and it works! But is there a way to not change the order of the other entries inside the list?
so to intial state:
V1
Duplicate1
Duplicate2
V2
V3

desired state:
V1
Duplicate2
V2
V3

Comment: @noob123 Sure, you need to specify one additional argument in the `toMap()`, namely *mapFactory*. Can you add this requirement to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your `ValueObject` class (not tested):

```
public class ValueObject {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String adress;

    // Constructor...

    // Getters and setters...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj == this ||(obj instanceof ValueObject
                    && ((ValueObject) obj).firstName.equals(this.firstName)
                    && ((ValueObject) obj).lastName.equals(this.lastName)
                );
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (firstName + lastName).hashCode();
    }
    
}
```

Then all you need is to use [`Stream#distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) to remove the duplicates

```
listWithDuplicates.getValues().stream().distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ValueObject::getLastname, Collectors.toList()));
```

You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334090/5645656) for a little more information about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does ist keep the lastest entry when using distinct?

Comment: @noob123 `distinct()` operation maintains a `LinkedHashSet` under the hood, and it would preserve the **first** encountered element in the stream from a group of elements identical according to the `equals()` method.

Comment: Please, don't get offended, but you're wrong (it's a matter of technical correctness, nothing personal) - the **first** encountered value would be preserved. Here's a [short code snippet](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/BwC) that proves that.

Comment: Here's what [`Set.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) contract says *"Adds the specified element to this set **if it is not already present**"*. Duplicated element would not be updated.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko thank you for pointing that out! I suppose I will just stick with my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot put it in a stream. But if you indeed create a equals method in the valueObject based on name and first name, you can filter based on the object. Put this in the ValueObject:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ValueObject that = (ValueObject) o;
        return Objects.equals(firstName, that.firstName) && Objects.equals(lastName, that.lastName);
    }
```

than it should you work fine with a loop like this:

```
List<ValueObject> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();

for(var vo: listWithDuplicates){
   if(!listWithoutDuplicates.contains(vo)){
        listWithoutDuplicates.add(vo);
         }
 }
```

But in a stream would be nicer, .. But you can work that out if you've implemented the equals method.

Answer (score 0):

I like the already provided answers, and think they give answer for you, but maybe for learning purposes, another approach could be to use a `Collector` that compares firstName and lastName fields of each ValueObject and then retains only the last instance of duplicates.

```
List<ValueObject> filteredList = listWithDuplicates.getValues().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(
            vo -> vo.getLastName() + vo.getFirstName(), 
            vo -> vo, 
            (vo1, vo2) -> vo2
        ), 
        map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())
    ));
```

So you would group the ValueObject instances by `lastName` and `firstName` using a COllector that creates a Map and the keys for the map are the concatenated `lastName` and `firstName`. The `collectingAndThen` collector transforms the Map into a List of ValueObjects.